# 'System.InvalidOperationException' when LINQ to SQL using WCF on WP8

Tags: c#, wcf, linq-to-sql, windows-phone-8

This is the code where the exception occurs:

```
public Listado()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ListadoWebService();
    }
    public void ListadoWebService()
    {
       // InitializeComponent();
        ServiceTours.ServiceToursClient cl = new ServiceTours.ServiceToursClient(); 
        cl.ListadoCompleted += new EventHandler<ListadoCompletedEventArgs>(Listado2);
        cl.ListadoAsync();
    }
    private void Listado2(object sender, ListadoCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        listB.ItemsSource = e.Result; // listB is ListBox in WP8
    }
```

I get following Exception:

`An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.ni.dll but was not handled in user code`

I would like to say that I directly followed this tutorial on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj684580%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

So the final Service Reference url is: http://**IP**/WcfTours/ServiceTours.svc as it should be. //99.99.99 represents IP

`World Wide Web Services (HTTP)` in `Allow an app through Windows Firewall` is allowed for `domain` `public` and `private`.

`Virtual Directory` is created.

Will somebody please help me with setting the `endpoint` please ?

Exception message:

`{System.InvalidOperationException: An endpoint configuration section for contract 'ServiceTours.IServiceTours' could not be loaded because more than one endpoint configuration for that contract was found. Please indicate the preferred endpoint configuration section by name.
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LookupChannel(String configurationName, String contractName, Boolean wildcard)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadChannelBehaviors(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, String configurationName)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration(String configurationName)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint(String configurationName, EndpointAddress address)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(String endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
   at System.ServiceModel.EndpointTrait`1.CreateSimplexFactory()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelFactoryRef(EndpointTrait`1 endpointTrait)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.InitializeChannelFactoryRef()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1..ctor()
   at PhoneApp1.ServiceTours.ServiceToursClient..ctor()
   at PhoneApp1.Listado.ListadoWebService()
   at PhoneApp1.Listado..ctor()}`

Comment: Please tell us the exception message.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth thank you for your interest helping me. Please see the edit.

Comment: Now, please read it and act according to it. :-) If you don't know how to, ask *specific* questions about the error message

Comment: You just have to specify an endpoint configuration name in ServiceToursClient constructor.

Comment: @VladimirGondarev May I please ask how it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you add a Web Service reference in your project a new ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file is created in the root folder of your project. Open it somewhere and look for:

```
<client>
    <endpoint .... name="endpointName" />
<endpoint .... name="endpointName2" />
</client>
```

In your case you have more than one records there. so select the appropriate and pass the name into contructor of ServiceToursClient.

```
new ServiceToursClient("endpointName")
```